# PHPMailer GMAIL XOAUTH2 with multiple GMAIL accounts for multiple virtual hosts

Tags: php, phpmailer, gmail-api

I host a web application that each client uses a different host name. I have successfully configured PHPMailer in the application to allow the client to enter their own SMTP information and send emails. Unfortunately, when the client uses Google's email service, the client needs to configure Gmail to allow less secure email clients. Instead of requiring the client to allow less secure email clients, I would like to use setup XOAUTH2.

All of the instructions I found setting up XOAUTH2 with Google's APIs, configure one host. I would like to setup XOAUTH2 allow multiple hosts without manually adding a new host to Google's API. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The way Oauth2 works your going to have to configure the redirect uri in google developer console..  Remember when you verify the app its probably going to require that you verfy that you own all these domains. [Xoauth2](https://developers.google.com/gmail/imap/xoauth2-protocol)

Comment: You might be better off getting your clients to create app-specific passwords, which do not require the "less secure apps" setting. It's much easier to manage than XOAUTH2.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can. I don't remember if in the callback urls you can put differents domains for the same application (I never tested that). But the consents screen can use only one.

Comment: Thank you for your response.

I am trying to complete my objective with one domain and multiple hosts.